# Web-Application Security with Apache Shiro Configuration Problems

Tags: java, security, web-applications, shiro

I decided to use Shiro to secure my webapplication. I use a tomcat app server, maven, hibernate and jsf. Now I tried to configure Shiro but got some problems.

Here are my files:

---POM.xml---

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0-incubating</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0-incubating</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
                    <artifactId>shiro-aspectj</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0-incubating</version>
            </dependency>
```

---web.xml---

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>

                  [main]

                  myrealm = com.misPartidos.web.MyRealm

         </param-value>

    </init-param>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

If I deploy to the server I get this error message:

```
ERROR: Exception starting filter ShiroFilter
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
30.07.2010 10:14:34 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
ERROR: Error filterStart
```

Where is my mistake? Do I need to implemnt something else as well?
Thank you for help
Sven

---

### Additional

I thought a bit about the problem. I think the key is to set the realm. But to test this framework I don't want to add a database or ldap. I need an easy solution...

---

### Update

I changed the web.xml as follows:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>

        [main]

        [users]

        tom = secret, admin
        paul = secret, user

        [roles]

        admin = *
        user = *

         </param-value>

    </init-param>
```

But the error remains the same :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not related to the INI configuration or your Realm definition.  It is because the org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter class is not in the classpath.  This class is in the shiro-web-1.0.0-incubating.jar file (no snapshot needed).  Ensure that your POM dependencies list it correctly.

Also, in your project's web module, run 'mvn install'.  Then look in the 'target' directory and you should see the built .war file.  On the command line, run 'jar tf my-war-file.war'.  As long as you see the shiro-web-1.0.0-incubating.jar file in /WEB-INF/lib, that is all that is required.

Cheers,

Les

(Apache Shiro team)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't spot anything obvious and things looks ok but still, the `ClassNotFoundException` suggests that `org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter` is not on the classpath (although your pom dependencies looks ok as I said). So could you check that:

- `shiro-web-1.0.0-incubating.jar` is packaged as expected in your war.
- your version of `shiro-web-1.0.0-incubating.jar` does contain that class.

---

Regarding your real definition, if you don't want to provide a realm implementation, why don't you simply define some users and roles as suggested in the documentation of the [INI Sections](http://incubator.apache.org/shiro/configuration.html#Configuration-INISections):

> Just defining non-empty `[users]` or `[roles]` sections will automatically trigger the creation of an `org.apache.shiro.realm.text.IniRealm` and make it available in the `[main]` section under the name iniRealm. You can configure it like any other object as described above.

For testing purposes, I think you should simply define a small static set of user accounts in the [[users]](http://incubator.apache.org/shiro/configuration.html#Configuration-%5Cusers%5C) section, as suggested:

> The [users] section allows you to define a static set of user accounts. This is mostly useful in environments with a very small number of user accounts or where user accounts don't need to be created dynamically at runtime. Here's an example:

Refer to the documentation for the exact syntax.

Comment: Thank you Pascal, I have read parts of the docu but for no reason not that part. Beginning with Java Web Development with all its frameworks are overwhelming somehow... -.- Thank u again

Comment: @Sven: Well, you're welcome... but it didn't solve the problem. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Some of tutorial as  web project's  pom.xml file defined  inadequate , for example my web project with shiro only worked after i deleted dependency  Shiro-core and added commons-logging  dependency to my pom.xml file